# Re-asking a user for their location on their next visit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Using the google maps api v3 I have created a map with a custom overlay to show a site plan of the area.
I have also added geolocation to it so that if a user accepts the popup asking for their location they can view where they are on the site plan. If they decline then they just get the basic site plan.

The problem is, sometimes a user might want their location shown, other times they may not, but it would seem that the browsers remember your first choice and that's that. How do I make it so that every time someone visits a page they get asked?

If that's not practical, is there a way to set the time-out on the permission?

Thanks

Comment: I think this might be down to the browser's implementation. For instance in Chrome it seems to remember the choice, but in Firefox it only remembers it once unless I choose to Always Share Location

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I know I can clear the permission manually for testing but that doesn't help for the public site.

Comment: Do you suppose it does it based on the URL of the page you're on, or of the URL of the javascript that's making the geolocation request?  Regardless, you could try appending a random URL parameter to either your page or the Google Maps JS request, and see if that prevents it

Comment: I think chrome (cant speak for other browsers) approves it on a domain level as the domain is listed under location services followed either by allow or deny. I've just tried adding a random parameter at the end of the url and it still goes through as approved.

It could be that this isnt something that can be fixed